# Flutter Dynamic PopupMenu Content

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a menu that has a 'load more' functionality. From an interface perspective, PopupMenuButton has worked nicely, but I've been unable to dynamically refresh its content.

I'm using redux and I can successfully dispatch the action to fetch more, and the store is updated, but I don't see the change until I close the menu and re-open it, despite wrapping the PopupMenuButton in a StoreConnector. I also have a check for fetchInProgress that should be changing the bottom 'more' item to a spinner while the fetch is in progress, but that state change isn't noticed either.

I'm relatively new to Flutter so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

[Gif of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHxV.gif)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => _ViewModel.fromStore(store, oneOnOneId),
      builder: (ctx, vm) => PopupMenuButton(
        onSelected: (callback) => callback(),
        icon: Icon(Icons.expand_more),
        itemBuilder: (_) =>
        [...vm.pastOneOnOnes.map((m) {
          return PopupMenuItem(
            child: Center(child: Text(DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').format(m.meetingDate))),
            value: () => {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName,
                arguments: {
                  'meetingId': m.id
                })
            }
          );
        }).toList(),
        PopupMenuItem(
          enabled: false,
          child: Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: vm.fetchInProgress ?
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) :
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => vm.fetchPastOneOnOnes(oneOnOneId, start: vm.pastOneOnOnes.length + 1),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('More', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
              )
            ),
          ),
          value: null
        )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did u find a solution? i am at the same situation. I have a list in a PopupMenubtn and i want to delete an item in the popupmenu and it should update while its open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state when you make a change. When you call `=> vm.fetchPastOneOnOnes` wrap it with `setState` :

```dart
    onTap: () {
setState(){
 vm.fetchPastOneOnOnes(...);}},
```

Comment: The widget isn't stateful, it's a stateless widget with a StoreConnector. Updates to the app state (redux) propagate changes to the connected widgets and trigger the builder.